# Understanding C++ Primer 5th ed solution posted by Moothy section 2.21

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm newbie to C++ and i'm working through exercises on chapter 2.
I have a question on exercise 2.21.
This solution is given by Moothy found on GitHub

> Exercise 2.21
>   Explain each of the following definitions.
>    Indicate whether any are illegal and, if so, why.
>   int i = 0;
>   (a) double* dp = &i;
>   Answer:
>   (a): illegal, cannot initialize a variable of type 'double *' with an
>         rvalue of type 'int *'

I don't understand the last part of the answer " .. rvalue of int *".
The &i is the address of variable i and never was a pointer mentioned here.
 Why would he mention a pointer here? And why an rvalue of a pointer to an int?

Comment: `i` is an `int`, `&i` is the address of `i`, so a pointer to an `int`...

Comment: &i is the address of variable i, which is of type (int *) and is an rvalue, because it is on the right hand side of the assignment... and that isn't automatically convertible to a pointer to a double, because it results in gibberish

Comment: @LuchianGrigore &i is an address of i. Yes. But there's no pointer (which in essence an object too) mentioned which store that address. It's confusing to say an address of an object is a pointer to that address. They looks like 2 different things to me

Comment: @GradyPlayer Pls see my response to Luchian

Comment: @GradyPlayer I just don't see &i == int * .. To me they are 2 distinct separate entity

Comment: "It's confusing to say an address of an object is a pointer to that address." it is, but no one is saying that. An address of an object is (the value of) a pointer to that object.

Comment: pointers aren't exactly an easy concept, and the notation that they chose to represent them maybe makes things less intuitive... but regardless ... `address of some var` , has a type, and if you want to store it the type that you use is `pointer to type of some var`

Comment: The last part of the answer is not "rvalue of `int *`" but "an rvalue *of type* `int*`". This should be read as  `&i` is of type `int*` and `&i` is also an rvalue. You can't have `&i` on the left hand side of an expression.

Answer (score 1):

> `int*` means a variable which can contain address of a integer
>   variable. Now address of an integer variable when placed on the right
>   hand side of the assignment then the left hand side should be `int*`
>   otherwise it will give wrong results. That's what is told here.

---

Where is the pointer? 
`dp` is a pointer but not an integer pointer that's why the error.

`rvalue`- the value that appears in the rhs of assignment operator.
A=B (r-value)

> Do you know why we need different pointers? Suppose you have a pointer
>   variable pointing to a chunk of integers.

```
BBBBBBB (bytes) 
| 
pointer(p) 

BBBBBBB (bytes) 
   |
   p+1 if pointing to int
BBBBBBB
 |
 p+1 if ointing to char
```

> Now if we say p++, then where do we move.
>   Okay if it is pointing to int move( sizeof(int)) 4 bytes , if
>   character 1 byte. Now say you are allowed to do wrong r-value
>   assignment. then it will be very problematic. You have to careful
>   enoough to code it properly.

Now hope you understand the whole picture.

Note:Look it is saying you can not initialize a `double *` with an `r-value of int*`. What is the r-value of an `int *`? it is address of an integer variable. So you are assigning to a `double pointer an r-value of int*` not r-value of `double*` which is an address of a `double`.

### FROM MSDN

> Every C++ expression is either an lvalue or an rvalue. An lvalue
>   refers to an object that persists beyond a single expression. You can
>   think of an lvalue as an object that has a name. All variables,
>   including nonmodifiable (const) variables, are lvalues. An rvalue is a
>   temporary value that does not persist beyond the expression that uses
>   it. To better understand the difference between lvalues and rvalues,
>   consider the following example:

[example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90831hc.aspx)

For further example/clarification check this SO question

[exact-difference-between-rvalue-and-lvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357888/exact-difference-between-rvalue-and-lvalue)

Comment: @yapkm01.:Check the answer..hope this will be helpful

Comment: Yes. i understand what an rvalue is. It's basically an expression where no location is specified .. e.g a temporary storage like in registry. I also do understand it's on RHS. But why would you say int * a rvalue eventhough it's on RHS? To me a int * an rvalue means there's no memory location for this int pointer. How about int* p = &i;  Is int*p an rvalue? I know it's on the LHS but i just want to see what's the different int *p on LHS and int *p on RHS ..

Comment: @yapkm01.:Look it is saying you can not initialize a `double *` with an `r-value of int*`. What is the r-value of an `int *`? it is address of an integer variable. So you are assigning to a `double pointer an r-value of int*` not r-value of `double*` which is an address of a `double`.

Comment: @yapkm01.: The explanation part is given in answer..check it. I

Comment: what's the difference int * p on the LHS and int *q on the RHS? why would you call int *p an ivalue and int *q a rvalue? Both has value which can be changed .. sorry .. see don't see the picture .. maybe later i will

Comment: @yapkm01.: Look they seem same but on RHS it means that it must be assigned to proper l-value(that is one who can hold it(int*)).

Comment: @yapkm01.: Please upvote,downvote or accept the answer as that is what makes this post useful to future users.

Comment: i can't yet. I still don't see it. My confusion lies with why int * on RHS is consider rvalue. Int * is always assignable. It's not like comparing a=b+c and b+c=a .. yes this is clear cut since b+c is not assignable .. but an int * can always has its value changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80205/discussion-between-coderredoc-and-yapkm01).

Answer (score 0):

'dp' is a pointer to an double-value and the code wants it to point to an integer-value. This simply doesn't work. If 'dp' and 'i' weren't pointers, the value would be casted, but because you are working with pointers and not variables, this does not work.

Don't think to much about the given answer: That's compiler language and you will get a lot of sentences like that, but don't care about them now.